# Same Files Are in Different Size in IPAD1 and IPAD2 When I Retrieved Using ALAsset Block

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, file, alasset

I have synced an image  to 2 Ipads (Let Say IPAD1 and IPAD2) through ITunes.
Then ,when i retrieved the images using ALAssetLibrary block , the file size is different in 2 Ipads .

(IPAD1 File size: 0.024059,IPAD2 File size: 0.024325).

May i know, why the same files are in different size in  IPAD1 and IPAD2?

However i saved an image to IPAD1 and IPAD2 through the safari browser,by tapping the image from the same webpage,i got same file size for the image in Ipad1 and Ipad2 when i retrieved through ALAssetLibarary.

Please tell me your valuable suggestions....

Usage

---

```
I am doing the image comparison in Ipad PhotoLibrary.
Whenever an Image transfer request is coming from another device, i have to test the image file exist in PhotoLibrary.
So mentor image request will have CRC code of the requested image which will uneque for the same image file and i am generating the CRC code for all my photoLibrary images and comparing it with the requested image CRC code.
So whenever these 2 CRC's are equal , i can easily identify the files are same.
```

The code i used for retrieving PhotoLibrary Image is:

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
  {
   ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];

   NSLog(@"GOT ASSET, File size: %f", [rep size] / (1024.0f*1024.0f));

   uint8_t* buffer = malloc([rep size]);

   NSError* error = NULL;

   NSUInteger bytes = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0 length:[rep size] error:&error];

       if (bytes == [rep size])
       {   

            defaultRepresentationData = [[NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:bytes] retain];

            CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
            UIImage *photLibraryImage  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];


             NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photLibraryImage); //convert image into .png format.
             const int imageCRC = [self CRCForImage:imageData]]; //getting CRC value for image data

             NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"@@@@@@@@ image CRC is:%u",imageCRC ]);       

       }
       else
       {
            NSLog(@"Error '%@' reading bytes from asset: '%@'", [error localizedDescription]); //assetURL);
       }

   free(buffer);

   // notifies the lock that "all tasks are finished"

  };

     //
      ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
      {
           NSLog(@"NOT GOT ASSET");  
      };

  NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName]; 

   ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
   [assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl  resultBlock:resultblock  failureBlock:failureblock];    

 }
```

The   NSLog(@"GOT ASSET, File size: %f", [rep size] / (1024.0f*1024.0f)); printing different values for same file in different devices.

Console Log Details

---

Ipad1

---

GOT ASSET, File size: 0.024059
image CRC is:2659650838

Ipad2

---

GOT ASSET, File size: 0.024325
@@@@@@@@image CRC is:331786167

IPAD VERSION DETAILS

---

IPAD1:
    Version: 4.2.1(8C148)
    Model: MB292LL

IPAD2:
    Version: 4.3.5(8L1)
    Model: MB292LL

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's an implementation detail. There's no guarantee they'll be identical. Metadata (such as hardware info, serial number, time of day, etc.) may differ between the devices, for example.

If you tell us the broader goal you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to help you find an alternate solution to comparing file sizes.

Comment: I would like to add that a CRC checksum isn't enough to make sure that two images are the same!

Comment: Indeed. The pigeonhole principle tells us that a hash of *n* bits cannot distinguish between more than 2<sup>*n*</sup> values, and images are almost always more than 32 bits in length. The risk of collision between arbitrary data is so high as to be expected.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan@JustSid   for me also same issue found.
me also doing the image comparison in Ipad PhotoLibrary.
Whenever an Image transfer request is coming from another device, i have to test the image file exist in PhotoLibrary.
So may i know how can i test it? what are all the image details that i need to transfer from Sender device to Learner for PhotoLibrary image file exist check process?

Comment: Well, what objectively makes two images equal to each other?

Comment: just i synced an image to diffrent ipads(IPAD1 and IPAD2) through iTunes.
When i am transferring the synced image from IPAD1 to IPAD2 throufh WI-Fi, simply i need to check the image file exists in IPAD2 photolibrary.
In our case, the image file is exists(because we are synced early to both Ipads).So i need to get the curresponding image URL from IPAD2.thats the issue